# TableCell, getting its position in TableView

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, tablecell

How can I get position of TableCell in class implementation so I can do something like this: ?

```
@Override
public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

int x = thisCellColumnNumber();
int y = thisCellRowNumber();

if((x == 2) && (y == 3))
   setStyle(".....");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the actual `TableColumn` with `this.getTableColumn();`. If you really need the index, you could do

```
TableColumn<...> column = getTableColumn();
int colIndex = getTableView().getColumns().indexOf(column);
```

which is a bit ugly (and slow). However, just knowing the column should be enough. (Additionally, you really "know this already"; your table cell comes from a table cell factory, which is attached to a column; so you can always figure the column index and pass it to the cell when you create it.)

The row index is just

```
this.getIndex();
```

See the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html) for all available methods.

Comment: by  _so you can always figure the column index and pass it to the cell when you create it._ You mean something like this: `public class EditingCellNumbers extends TableCell<MyData, Integer>{ 
  private int thisCellColumnNumber`  and then pass column number to constructor?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. It assumes you're not dynamically adding and removing columns in a way that changes existing indexes, in which case you'd probably have to refer back to `getTableView().getColumns()` as shown earlier.

Comment: I was hoping there is quicker way to get column index just like this.getIndex() but I will figure out best way. Thanks!